# unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function

Tags: c++, pointers

I am using a  function that is taking the "pointer to function" as variable but program fail with the following error:

**error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  say '&EventCreatorBase::generateExceptionEvent'**

class ExceptionEvent {

```
 public:

    void cellEvent::generateEvents(const unsigned long* event, void(*overflowCallbackFn)(unsigned int));

};

class EventCreatorBase{ 
  public:
     void generateExceptionEvent(unsigned int);
     ..
     void fun1()
     {
       ...
       ExceptionEvent event1;
       const unsigned long* eventCounter;
       ..
       event1.generateEvents(eventCounter, &generateExceptionEvent); 
     }


};
```

Comment: Did you consider doing precisely as the compiler told you?

Comment: Hello every one! Quite long time when I have posted  this.  Thanks for your efforts but don't invest more time here :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert member-function pointer to function-pointer and by the way, your code is wrong.
Should be like

```
event1.generateEvents(eventCounter, &EventCreatorBase::generateExceptionEvent);
```

But it's also doesn't work, since you cannot convert member-function pointer to function-pointer. The best way it to use `std::function` with `std::bind`.

```
void cellEvent::generateEvents(const unsigned long* event,
const std::function<void(int)>&);
```

then just

```
event1.generateEvents(eventCounter,
std::bind(&EventCreatorBase::generateExceptionEvent, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

If you cannot use C++11 - you can use boost::function/boost::bind.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here: 
a. Wrong syntax for function pointer argument - you are saying it is a regular function pointer, but you want it to be a class member pointer. You need to use class name (and that means, you'd need the class forward-declared)
b. Compiler is saying exactly what needs to be fixed for the second error.